# PageTabVIewStyle() crashes the canvas preview

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview

I'm creating a small SwiftUI app with a TabView, but the code stopped working as soon as I used the modifier .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle()). Why is that? The app is meant to cycle through a series of images and is going to be similar in design to the Photos app. It's based on a Kavsoft tutorial, but that tutorial used deprecated code. When I used the more modern equivalent, the app's preview stopped working, and I can no longer see the TabView.

```
struct Home: View {
    
    /* Posts */
    @State var posts: [Post] = []
    
    /* Cuurent Image */
    @State var currentImage = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        /* Gallery */
        TabView(selection: $currentImage) {
            ForEach(posts) { post in
                /* GeometryReader to get screen sizes for image */
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    let size = geo.size
                    Image(post.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                        .cornerRadius(0)
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle()) // Cannot work
        .onAppear {
            for index in 1...10 {
                posts.append(Post(image: "\(index)"))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Post: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var image: String
}
```

Comment: Can you try it with basic content like `Text()`? My suspicion is that the `ForEach` is loading posts that doesn't exist yet, causing it to init with a nil set.

Comment: @brandonscript It works with basic text, and I also was able to get it to work by setting the posts array manually with Post objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer here for completeness, I suspected it would work with static content like `Text()`. This was crashing because `ForEach` is trying to load posts that don't exist yet, causing it to init from an empty array. For the tab view to work correctly, it needs at least one rendered view.

To fix this, `posts` needs to have at least one element in it to render.